# How can I restrict types based on input values in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

I'm new to Haskell. Sorry if this question has an obvious answer.

I have

```
data Tmp = Foo Int
         | Bar Int
         | Baz Int
```

and

```
data Test = A Tmp Tmp
```

The constructor `A Tmp Tmp` can take any constructor for `Tmp` except for
`A (Baz i) (Baz j)` where `i` and `j` are arbitrary `Int`s. Is there any way I can
restrict the second `Tmp` in `A Tmp Tmp` from being `Baz` if the first `Tmp` is already `Baz`?

Comment: The usual way to do this in Haskell is through a smart constructor `a :: Tmp -> Tmp -> Maybe Test`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer depends on how you want your restriction to be enforced: At runtime or at compile time.

**To enforce the restriction at runtime**, you can add a function (say, `makeA`) that checks the restriction and then calls the constructor. Such a function that does a bit of stuff and then calls a constructor is also called a *smart constructor*. If you only export the smart constructor `makeA` but not the real constructor `A` from a module, you can be sure that other modules use the smart constructor, so the restriction is always checked.

Example:

```
module Test (Tmp (Foo, Bar, Baz), Test (), makeA) where
  data Tmp
     = Foo Int
     | Bar Int
     | Baz Int

  data Test = A Tmp Tmp

  makeA :: Tmp -> Tmp -> Tmp
  makeA (Baz _) (Baz _) = error "makeA: two baz problem"
  makeA tmp1 tmp2 = A tmp1 tmp2
```

The benefit of this technique is that you don't have to change your data types at all. The drawback is that the restriction is only enforced at run time.

**To enforce the restriction at compile time**, you need to change your data types somehow. The problem with your current data types is that the type checker cannot distinguish values constructed by `Foo` and `Bar` and values constructed by `Baz`. To the type checker, these are all `Tmp` values, so the type checker cannot enforce that some `Tmp` values are ok and others aren't. So we have to change the data types to encode "Bazness" of a `Tmp` value in the types.

**One option for encoding the Bazness in the type** would be to restructure `Tmp` as follows:

```
data TmpNotBaz
  = Foo Int
  | Bar Int

data Tmp
  = NotBaz TmpNotBaz
  | Baz Int
```

Now it is clear that a value of type `TmpNotBaz` cannot be `Baz`, but a value of type `Tmp` can be `Baz`. The benefit of this idea is that it only uses basic Haskell features. A minor drawback is that you need to put calls to `NotBaz` into your code. A major drawback is that we still cannot directly express the idea of "one of the arguments of `A` can be `Baz` if the other isn't". We would have to write multiple versions of `A`:

```
data Test
  = A1 TmpNotBaz Tmp
  | A2 Tmp TmpNotBaz
```

Now we can express all the values we want by choosing `A1` or `A2` as necessary, and we cannot express `A (Baz ...) (Baz ...)` anymore, as required. A problem with this solution is that there are multiple representations for what used to be, for example, `A (Foo 1) (Foo 2)` : Both `A1 (Foo 1) (NotBaz (Foo 2))` and `A2 (NotBaz (Foo 1)) (Foo 2)` represent this value.

You can try to play around with the structure of the datatypes like this and create a version that works for your situation.

**Another option for encoding the Bazness in the type** would be to annotate a bit of type-level information to the `Tmp` type and use type-level programming to reason about this type-level information. The drawback of this idea is that it uses more advanced Haskell features. Actually, there are many emerging ways to do this sort thing, and it is not clear which of these will end up being considered "standard" advanced Haskell. That said, here is one approach:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeFamilies, DataKinds #-}

data Bazness = IsBaz | NotBaz

data BothBazOrNot = BothBaz | NotBothBaz

type family AreBothBaz (b1 :: Bazness) (b2 :: Bazness) :: BothBazOrNot where
  AreBothBaz 'IsBaz 'IsBaz = 'BothBaz
  AreBothBaz _ _ = 'NotBothBaz

data Tmp (b :: Bazness) :: * where
  Foo :: Int -> Tmp 'NotBaz
  Bar :: Int -> Tmp 'NotBaz
  Baz :: Int -> Tmp 'IsBaz

data Test where
  A :: AreBothBaz b1 b2 ~ 'NotBothBaz => Tmp b1 -> Tmp b2 -> Test
```

Note how the type signatures of the constructors `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` talk about whether the constructor creates something that `IsBaz` or `NotBaz`. And how the type signature for `A` talks about some `b1` and `b2` choices so that `NotBothBaz`.

Using this code, we can write the following expressions:

- `A (Foo 1) (Bar 2)`
- `A (Foo 1) (Baz 2)`
- `A (Baz 1) (Bar 2)`

But if we try to write  `A (Baz 1) (Baz 2)`, the type checker complains:

```
Couldn't match type 'BothBaz with 'NotBothBaz
    arising from a use of A
 In the expression: A (Baz 1) (Baz 2)
```

So the type checker figured out that in this case, the arguments to `A` are `BothBaz`, but we annotated the type of `A` to only accept arguments that are `NotBothBaz`, so the type checker complains that `BothBaz` differs from `NotBothBaz`.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer!